# Django rest API deploy on apache

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, rest

I have created a django application and deployed it on the server.I have run the application through :-
`python manage.py runserver 8000 &`

and handle the requests on the apache server through proxy

`ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://www.example.com/"`.

But there is a issue that I am facing while testing the api through JMeter, when i am running a test case for 10 users my python service over the server gets killed automatically.
What i am doing wrong or what i have to do more to resolve the above test scenario,please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to deploy it on other server like `apache`. Below I am sharing how as usual configuration of apache2 to deploy a python django project.

- Considering virtual environment is created else see [how to create
  virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/)

**Apache installation:**
You need to install apache if not installed yet. Here I am showing the apache2 installation and some other installation which we need.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

**configuration of 000-default.conf file :** Generally the apache2 is located on linux m at path `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. And the configuration file may like that.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.something.com

    # this is the document root of your project
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my-project
    # The directory which you can access with base path EX: www.something.com/static/images/image.png
    Alias /static /path/to/my-project/static

    <Directory /path/to/my-project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/my-project/my-project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess my-project python-home=/path/to/my_env python-path=/path/to/my-project
    WSGIProcessGroup my-project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my-project/my-project/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog /path/to/my-project/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/my-project/logs/access.log combined3
</VirtualHost>
```

**Django project wsgi.py :** The django project you created there have a `wsgy.py` and this file may look like.

```
python_home = '/path/to/my_env'

import sys
import site

sys.path.append('/path/to/my-project')
sys.path.append('/path/to/my_env/bin')
sys.path.append('/path/to/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

# Calculate path to site-packages directory.

python_version = '.'.join(map(str, sys.version_info[:2]))
site_packages = python_home + '/lib/python%s/site-packages' % python_version

# Add the site-packages directory.

site.addsitedir(site_packages)

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my-project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

After that you can start you apache2 sever `sudo service apache2 start`

Also you need to give the permission of you project directory `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/my-project`

This is the basic configuration of apache2 with python django project. Hope this will help to configure any `linux machine` with your `python django project`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot using `python manage.py runserver 8000` on a server, it's for development ONLY.

You can see the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/

A basic conf for Apache would be :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yoursite.com
    ServerAdmin your@site.com

    Alias /media/ /path/to/django-app/media/

    <Directory /path/to/django-app/media/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django-app/conf/wsgi.py

    <Directory /path/to/django-app/conf/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to adapt this for your project.

If you need to install mod_wsgi : https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html

For me i would use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/ it's more convenient (`pip install uwsgi`)

Comment: can you please suggest me the method to deploy it on amazon(aws) linux server ?

Comment: Hi you can find a lot of tutorial on Google, i can give you one  with ngix : https://medium.com/@charlesthk/deploy-nginx-django-uwsgi-on-aws-ec2-amazon-linux-517a683163c6